# Can a PC move after freeing from grapple or restrained?

Tags: dnd-5e

The rules say that a creature with the grappled or restrained condition has a speed of 0. Player argues that a creature can't move on the same turn that it frees itself from either condition, because it started its turn with a speed of 0. Player citing pg. 181 of Players Handbook as reference:

> SPEED: Every character and monster has a speed, which is the distance in feet that the character or monster can walk in 1 round.

The claim is that, according to this statement, a creature that starts its turn grappled or restrained has a speed of 0 this round, therefore can't move until the next round after freeing itself from the condition.

My claim is that the creature gains its speed back IMMEDIATELY upon losing the condition, even on its turn, citing pg. 290 from the Players Handbook:

> A creature either has a condition or doesn't.

So: Can a creature move on the same turn that it eliminates either of these conditions from itself, or does it have to wait until its next turn to move?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jeremy Crawford kindly answered this for me: [Tweet from Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/redwullf/status/722476584314089472)

> @jeremycrawford The effects of a condition end the moment the condition ends.

Comment: A second half of the answer, which might begin with "and so ..." and directly answer the question, is something that would be good to add.

Answer (score 18):

You are correct.

On page 189 of the PHB.

> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed and take one
>   action. **You decide whether to move first or take your action first**.

So if you take your action first and end the grappled condition, you then can take your move at your speed.

Because as you correctly stated  on page 290 a condition no longer applies if the character no longer has it. Since the condition ends **before** the character has taken his move. His speed reverts to normal.

Comment: This answer could be improved if directly addresses whether a creature can stand up after breaking free from grappled.

Comment: The Grappled condition and the Prone condition are separate. In any case if a creature was grappled and prone. Then the rule would that after they break the grapple, they could either crawl, or lose half of their move to get up.