# How do mixed movement modes work with the alternate encumbrance rules?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, encumbrance

We use the alternate encumbrance rules, where you only can carry your Strength times 5 pounds unencumbered. Per the rules, up to that weight, you can move your speed in a round.  When you are encumbered you get slowed down by 10 feet, and when heavily encumbered by 20 feet. If the load is so heavy you only can drag it, your speed gets reduced to 5 feet.

What happens if a character has used some movement, and at that point picks up something heavy that alters their encumbrance and speed, especially if it is so heavy they can only drag it?

For a practical example from today's game, a character went down in combat. His fighter friend moved towards him (using up 10 feet of his 30 feet of speed). He already was loaded close to the maximum of his unencumbered carrying capacity of 80 pounds, due to armor, weapons, and heavy sacks of loot. The fallen character with their equipment weighed close to 240 pounds. This meant their own equipment, and the fallen character together, were a load of close to 320 pounds. At that point, with Strength 16, that was heavier than the limit of 16 x 15 = 240 pounds for heavy encumbrance, so their only option was to drag them -- that works up to 16 x 30 = 480 pounds.

So, can the fighter still drag his friend? The movement gets replaced then by 5 feet of movement, but not all the movement is available to be replaced any more, as a third of it has already been used up.

Comment: Related question on [How do changes to your speed that occur on your own turn affect your available movement?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152351/how-do-changes-to-your-speed-that-occur-on-your-own-turn-affect-your-available-m)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The way the [rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovementandPosition) say

> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed.

> However you're moving, you deduct the distance of each part of your move from your speed until it is used up or until you are done moving.

> If you have more than one speed, such as your walking speed and a flying speed, you can switch back and forth between your speeds during your move. Whenever you switch, subtract the distance you've already moved from the new speed. The result determines how much farther you can move. If the result is 0 or less, you can't use the new speed during the current move.

Combined with these [rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#VariantEncumbrance).

> While pushing or dragging weight in excess of your carrying capacity, your speed drops to 5 feet.

> If you carry weight in excess of 5 times your Strength score, you are encumbered, which means your speed drops by 10 feet.

> If you carry weight in excess of 10 times your Strength score, up to your maximum carrying capacity, you are instead heavily encumbered, which means your speed drops by 20 feet …

So, for your example, the PC is encumbered and so has a speed 10 less than normal. You don’t say what their unencumbered speed is, we’ll call it \$s\$.

They move 10 feet to their buddy. If 10<\$s\$-10 they still have movement remaining.

Picking up their buddy would put them over their maximum lifting capacity, so they can’t do that. However, they can push or drag them which makes their speed 5 feet. Now 5 speed is less than the 10 feet they have already moved so their movement is over.

If you haven’t used your action this turn, you can [Dash](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Dash) to “gain extra movement for the current turn. The increase equals your speed, after applying any modifiers.” So, another 5 feet, which doesn’t help because of the new total of 10 feet you’ve already used 10 feet. If you could Dash again, through the Fighter’s Action Surge or the Rogue’s Cunning Action, say, you could get another 5 feet which you could use.

You need to remember that how far you *have* moved is never subtracted from how far you *can* move. These are always two seperate numbers that are constantly compared to one another - if the first is bigger than the second, you can continue to move, if it isn’t, you can’t. How far you can move can change up or down, how far you have moved only ever increases.

Comment: I don't agree with the dash part of your explanation, it makes no sense at all to count the new movement from dash as part of the same movement of getting to the heavy object (friend). You can't have negative movement as far as I am aware, so the -5 would count as 0, and dash would still work.

Comment: @SeriousBri You might not agree; that would make you wrong, but that's your prerogative. The rules on Dash are quite clear - you get extra movement equal to your adjusted speed.

Comment: But do they state that you can have negative movement? Because I don't think so, that's why I disagree. If they do state you can have negative movement, then you can add it and convince me otherwise.

Comment: @SeriousBrithey do not state you can have negative movement, and you don’t. They do state that you can have expended more movement than you currently have. For example, if you have a speed of 30 and a fly speed of 60 and you fly 40 feet and then lose your ability to fly (fly speed 0 - which isn’t negative), you have a speed of 30 and have moved 40, meaning you can’t move any further, not that you have a negative speed. If you increase your speed by 10, you still can’t move.

Comment: I may have worded the example not in the clearest way saying "encumbered close to..", the fighter had a normal speed of 30, and was unencumbered, but near the threshold. I will update the qeustion to clarify. I think I can accept this as the RAW solution. It feels weird that if you even step 5 feet, you cannot later drag anyone any more without Dashing, as you used so small a share of your available movement, but if that is how it works, that is how it works.

Comment: The bit that I am not sure about is that if you go to -10 it stays at 0, which is probably true, but then when you get more movement it suddenly remembers that you were actually at -10 and takes it off you? I think that specific assertion needs support. The rules that you have quoted that may support it are referring to switching travel modes, not dashing (although they may cover both, but it isn't clear in the answer and dash is not an alternative travel mode). I am slowly coming around to this, but not quite convinced yet.

Comment: @SeriousBri the mistake you are making is that you are subtracting the amount you moved from how far you can move - that’s not how it works. There are always two different numbers - how far you can move in total which can change up or down and how far you have moved which can only increase, and these numbers are compared to one another. If the first is bigger than the second, you can continue to move, if it is t, you can’t.

Comment: I think the rules you quote cover that in terms of different movement types, but not necessarily for dash. That said I have been convinced pretty far from my original position so thank you (it's rare I let people chance my mind lol). I will dig out some dash rules and see what I can see.